# Amazon S3 configuration with Broadleaf Commerce

Tags: broadleaf-commerce

I have been able to successfully host the Broadleaf Commerce Site on Amazon Beanstalk, but not yet able to configure the Assets (product images) settings.
Since EC2 does not provide persistent data storage , I believe the images needs to be stored with some external CDN. I am going with Amazon S3.

I followed all the steps given in this tutorial. http://www.broadleafcommerce.com/docs/amazon/current/module-installation

and I think my application have configured it successfully, since I don't see any anything wrong in the tomcat logs.

What additional settings do I need to change so that product Images are fetched from S3 instead of the local directory(which is configured by default)

Answer (score 3):

I followed the same documentation as you did but was getting few exceptions so I switched to version 1.1.0-GA of broadleaf-amazon in root pom. The dependency looks like below in my pom.xml:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.broadleafcommerce</groupId>
            <artifactId>broadleaf-amazon</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0-GA</version>
            <type>jar</type>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
```

You might get it done with 1.0.1-GA as well but suggesting above since that has worked for me. I am able to store my assets e.g. images in the S3 bucket. If you have followed the documentation correctly and make the above change, you should be good to go as far as Broadleaf configuration is concerned.

However there is still a thing which you need to do in your AWS account.

1. Go to AWS IAM Management Console.
2. Switch to Roles using left navigation and find a role named "aws-elasticbeanstalk-ec2-role"
3. And attach "AmazonS3FullAccess" policy to it.

This way you are giving read/write access to EC2 in order to fetch/store your static assets e.g. images.

Above has worked for me quite well. It should work for you too.

Comment: Thanks Jitesh, Its been long I posted this question, I was able to do the configuration meanwhile. This answer will be helpful for others.

Comment: any idea about this issue? http://forum.broadleafcommerce.org/viewtopic.php?f=11&t=23628

Comment: @Tushar this is the exception which I was getting with 1.0.1-GA. Try using 1.1.0-GA instead and you should be good to go.

Comment: unfortunately I am using 1.1.0-GA itself. :-/

Comment: @Tushar Extract broadleaf-amazon-1.1.0-GA and go to directory "org/broadleafcommerce/vendor/amazon/s3". Locate class file "S3FileServiceProvider.class". Decompile this file using any online decompiler and try to find method "addOrUpdateResourcesForPaths". Most likely you won't find it. If that's the case, you are saved. Your jar file downloaded is corrupt. Try downloading directly from http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.broadleafcommerce/broadleaf-amazon/1.1.0-GA or delete the jar from .m2 repo and let maven download it again. Check again, the method will be there now. That's it, done :)

Comment: umm, I am not sure this would solve this, because S3 configuration is working fine when environment variable is set to development. It just gets messed up after changing the env. I will try few other things. Will post solution if I find any. Thanks anyways !!

Comment: @Tushar That's what your error suggests anyway. It's not able to find the method "addOrUpdateResourcesForPaths". This has worked for me btw. Worth giving a try. Do post if something else does the trick for you.